# Reasons why am I struggling to connect node with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database-connection

I am having trouble connecting Node with MongoDB.

I have tested both of them separately and they work fine. I have also created a path for the db. What else could I be missing?

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

// Connect to the db
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/exampleDb", function(err, db) {
  if(!err) {
    console.log("We are connected");
  }
});
```

Comment: Did you try to do `console.log(err)` inside the function? It can help you figure out the problem

Comment: Try this Marina  { useNewUrlParser: true }

Comment: Please do console.log(err) and show us the error, so that we know whats going on.

Comment: Thank you for the help! My mistake was that I forgot to do 
npm install mongodb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
 /**
  * Open connection with database.
  */

   MongoClient.connect("exampleDb", { useNewUrlParser: true },    

   function(error, db) {
      if (error) {
          console.warn("MyDatabase : err1:" + error);
          return;
      }

       const dbo = db.db(databaseName);

      // Demo - Use it in usual way.
      // dbo.collection("users").findOne({ "email": email }, function(err, result) { 

      // });
```

You can find more explanation on :

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/27067

Answer (score 0):

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

// Connection URL
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

// Database Name
const dbName = 'myproject';

// Use connect method to connect to the server
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
  console.log("Connected successfully to server");

  const db = client.db(dbName);

  client.close();
});
```